# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want to create an app for betting and now I work on a page where the user can select and put matches' information.

My problem is in the pickerView for choosing the kind of match and then choosing a ligue. It works well but if I click out of the textfield where the pickerView is located and I come back on it, the app crashes on the line:

```
return typeM[selectedType].ligue[row]
```

The error is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

If someone can help me to fix it, that would be great.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit


class TypeM {
    var type: String
    var ligue: [String]

    init(type:String, ligue:[String]) {
        self.ligue = ligue
        self.type = type
    }
}

class AskViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    // MARK : variables page 1

    @IBOutlet weak var eqDom: Textfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var eqExt: Textfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var coteDom: Textfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var coteTie: Textfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var coteExt: Textfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var matchNulouPas: Boutons!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePickerTxt: Textfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeMatch: Textfield!

    var typeM = [TypeM]()
    var pickerViewTypesM = UIPickerView()

    // MARK : ViewDidLoad

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createDatePicker()

        eqDom?.delegate = self
        eqExt?.delegate = self

        typeMatch?.inputView = pickerViewTypesM
        typeMatch?.textAlignment = .center
        typeMatch?.placeholder = "select Type"
        pickerViewTypesM.delegate = self
        pickerViewTypesM.dataSource = self
        typeM.append(TypeM(type: "Championnat", ligue: ["ENG Premier League","ENG Championship","ESP Liga 1","ESP Liga 2","FRA Ligue 1","FRA Ligue 2","GER Bundesliga","GER Bundesliga 2","ITA Serie A","ITA Serie B"]))
        typeM.append(TypeM(type: "International Cup", ligue: ["UEFA Champions League","Europa League","Club World Cup","Country World Cup","Concacaf Champions League","Euro","Confederations Cup","Copa America"]))
    }

    // MARK : menu type match

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {return 2}

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return typeM.count
        } else {
            let selectedType = pickerViewTypesM.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return typeM[selectedType].ligue.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return typeM[row].type
        } else {
            let selectedType = pickerViewTypesM.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return typeM[selectedType].ligue[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        pickerViewTypesM.reloadComponent(0)
        pickerViewTypesM.reloadComponent(1)

        let selectType = pickerViewTypesM.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectligue = pickerViewTypesM.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let type = typeM[selectType].type
        let ligue = typeM[selectType].ligue[selectligue]

        typeMatch.text = "--> : \( type,"" + ligue)"
    }

    // MARK : menu championnats

    // MARK : chgmnt couleur bouton X
    @IBAction func eskeNul(_ sender: Any) {
        if matchNulouPas.backgroundColor == UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) {
            matchNulouPas.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.74, green: 0.74, blue: 0.74, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            matchNulouPas.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

    // MARK : retour clavier

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    // MARK : date picker

    let picker = UIDatePicker()

    func createDatePicker() {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

        datePickerTxt?.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        datePickerTxt?.inputView = picker

        picker.datePickerMode = .date
    }

    @objc func donePressed() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)

        datePickerTxt.text = "\(dateString)"
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, `index out of range` means that you're trying to access an item at an index, bigger than there are items. For instance: say you have an array of 3 items. If you put `array[3]`, it'll be out of range, because the index 3 would look for the 4th item, which simply isn't there. (Remember: indices start at 0, whereas counts start at 1)

Comment: ohhh ok thanks, I understand, but despite this, I can not find my mistake

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant for debugging. However, to help you get on the right path: find the spots where you access an array. Then figure out at which line it crashes (put print statements before them or place breakpoints) and then figure out why the index is out of range.

Comment: What is the value of `selectedType` when you get the error?

Comment: it's when "International Cup" is selected in the first component, so I guess selectedType has this value

Comment: Don't guess. Use the debugger and see what the actual value is.

Comment: ok, so the value of selctedType when I get the error is :      ["UEFA Champions League", "Europa League", "Club World Cup", "Country World Cup", "Concacaf Champions League", "Euro", "Confederations Cup", "Copa America"]

Comment: Huh? `selectedType` will be an `Int`, not an array.